# Which Java EE technology stack is best for data driven application?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, struts, ejb

I have to design and develop a data driven application from scratch to administer many things in our company and for that I decided to go Java EE way. In past I worked on application which were running on Struts-EJB2.0-Hibernate kind of stack but during my recent research lot of people suggested to use Spring. So here are some of my options, but I am not sure which one is the best for our requirements:
Struts-Spring-Hibernate
Struts2/JSF-Spring-Hibernate
Spring MVC-Spring-Hibernate
Spring MVC-Spring-Spring ORM
Struts-Spring+EJB3.0-Hibernate

Our main expectation from this application are:

1. Modular and extensible(ease of adding new modules/functionalities on this platform)
2. Easy web services development(for integration with other products)
3. Good transaction management and ORM(because it is a data driven application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very open ended. I would use something that you are more comfortable with. As far as data driveness is concerned you have hibernate is pretty good. I am not familiar with Spring ORM, but hibernate is something that is used extensively.

Comment: I have worked with Struts 1.x+EJB2.0+Hibernate in past but now a days everybody is saying that Struts 1.x and EJB2.0 thing of past and way to future is Spring so thought of going with Spring. Moreover it provides All-in-one package for application development in terms of technology stack.

Answer (score 1):

Rule Spring out. Give Java EE 6 a try. Spring solves many problems that existed in J2EE, but don't exist anymore. Nowadays, doing Java EE applications is far easier than before, with the additional advantage that you don't get attached to a single vendor.

Comment: Apart from more vendors for JEE6, is there any concrete reason to choose it over Spring? I am fine with Apache as single vendor if Spring gives me everything I want to build a highly modular and scalable application. If you wanted to point out certain vendor who did things better than Spring, please let me know. My experience with JSF+ICEFaces was not so good in the past so this time I am trying to go to Spring path.

Comment: By single vendor I mean SpringSource, not Apache. There are several advantages in adopting an official standard than a single-company product (like Spring). One of the advantages is that you know there will be several vendors out there to support you in case you need. You don't have to worry if one of them becomes "evil" ;-) Another advantage is about resources: it's usually easier to find developers with knowledge about some well-established standard than with knowledge about a particular product. So, I'd go with the standard JEE over a specific product. I really don't like vendor lock-in.